# Replacement for 2w 1.1 ohm fuse/fusible resistor of Samsung Mobile charger

Tags: resistors, charger, fuses

I have a Samsung Mobile Charger (type-c) with the model name **EP-TA800** and it has stopped working.
I opened the case and found a fuse (fusible resistor) labeled **2w1.1ohm** that had failed so when I desoldered it and bypassed the fuse with a wire I could get a 5 volt output from the charger and so it seems the problem is with the fuse.
Now what are the options and alternatives for the replacement of this fuse?
Here is also a [link](https://www.chargerlab.com/samsungs-first-usb-c-charger-ep-ta800-teardown-review/) to some description of the components (including the fuse) used in the (similar to mine) charger.

*So in fact I want to know what kind of **fuse** (what **amperage** and **voltage**, ...)  is required in front of a **220v input** and before the rectifier circuit of a mobile battery charger with the maximum output current (based on the charger's casing description) of 3.0A.*

*Does a 250v 3A SMD fuse do the job properly?*

[image: fuse]

Comment: What suggests to you that this is a fuse and not a low-resistance resistor, e.g. for current sensing? It's unwise to make such assumptions in a mains-connected device which could either electrocute you or damage your phone if it malfunctions and you then make an incorrect fix.

Comment: If that were a fuse then it would have a current rating (in **A**mps), not a resistance (in \$\Omega\$) and a power (in W).

Comment: In the link that I have provided above the author says it is a fusible resistor.

Comment: Ok - so it's a fusible *resistor*, not a resistible fuse. So you need to preplace it with another fusible *resistor*, not a fuse (or maybe a resistor and a fuse in series).

Comment: Then, what could be the details and specifications of the combinations of the fuse and the resistor if I cannot find the exact fusible resistor spare component?

Comment: @mhmdghfr A couple of minutes of searching yielded [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nte-electronics-inc/F2W1D1/11649402) which has a matching resistance, power rating, and fusible feature. A new charger could very well be cheaper and safer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for some extremely cheap (but safe) alternative. Maybe a 2watt1ohm resistor plus some kind of small fuse (maybe priced at a few cents, though I am not from USA). Of course one can always buy a new charger, but I intend to fix this one properly, for fun and experience.